# How can i get classname of element of foreach in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, element, classname

```
const dropdownmenu = document.querySelector(".dropdownmenu")

dropdownmenu.forEach(element => {
    
    console.log(element.classname)
    
});
```

Question is How can i get classname of element of foreach in Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. `document.querySelector` only selects one element - the first element that matches the specified selector. You should use `document.querySelectorAll` to grab an array of elements.
2. `.classname` should be camelcased -> `.className`

I'm assuming you are trying to grab the elements inside of the dropdown menu. Here's how you'd do that:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="item">item1</li>
    <li class="item">item2</li>
    <li class="item">item3</li>
</ul>

<script>
    const menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu')

    for (const elem of menu.querySelectorAll('.item')) {
        console.log(elem.className);
    }
</script>
```

If you're trying to listen for events on the dropdown menu for all of the items, try putting the event listener right on the parent and using `e.target` to target the clicked child.

```html
<p>Click the items</p>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="item">item1</li>
    <li class="item">item2</li>
    <li class="item">item3</li>
</ul>

<script>
    const menu = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');

    menu.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.textContent);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So how can i understand using "addEventListener" that i which button i click ? I mean, i'm trying to make a dropdown menu using javascript.

Comment: At that point, you want to add the event listener right on the parent element, rather than on every single dropdown item.

Comment: Can you give me an example about your said thing ?

Comment: @MutluŞEN Check my updated answer :D It's there